# Python naming conventions in decorators

Tags: coding-style, python

Are there any "accepted" naming conventions for the innards of Python decorators?

The [style guide](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) doesn't mention it, and [this awesome entry about decorators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/739654/understanding-python-decorators) is pretty consistent in using variants of "wrapped" for the ultimate function that is returned, but what about the names used when creating decorators that take arguments?

```
def decorator_name(whatevs):
    def inner(function):
        def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
            # sweet decorator goodness
        return wrapped
    return inner
```

Specifically, what are the conventions for `inner`, `function`, and `wrapped` in the above example?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

There are no standardized conventions (such as PEPs) for those names. If you check the python stdlib you'll find lots of different names for those functions.

However, `decorator` is a rather common name for the decorator function `inner`.
It is also common to call your `wrapped` function `wrapper` and decorate it with [`functools.wraps(f)`](http://docs.python.org/library/functools.html#functools.wraps) with `f` being the wrapped function (`func` is also a common name for it).

```
def decorator_name(whatevs):
    def decorator(f):
        @wraps(f)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            pass # sweet decorator goodness
        return wrapper
    return decorator
```

Comment: Eh, if you have a single-argument function named `decorator` then it's pretty clear what its argument is no matter what it's called.

Comment: Calling the inner function `decorator` is probably a very good idea, since `decorator_name` is not really a decorator but a *decorator factory*, and the multiple layers of nested function definition can be a little confusing.

Comment: Why abbreviate `function`? I asked this [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10957789/using-the-name-function-for-a-variable-in-python-code), too.

Comment: @MikeStringer I find myself using f or _f or g because it conforms to math notation (e.g. `f(x)`) and emphasizes that the function being passed doesn't need to be restricted in and of itself. (as opposed to a key function or comparison function, or a function that only takes one argument, etc).

Comment: Where are `args` and `kwargs` defined in this example?

Comment: can you explain why you use 3 nested methods instead of 2? Even the [functools.wraps(f) docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.wraps) use only two.

Comment: @David because the decorator accepts arguments, which means that in `@foo(...)` the `foo` function actually needs to return the decorator that is them applied to the function (foo gets called at import time and then the return value of foo decorates your function)

Answer (score 2):

By definition, a decorator in Python could be a function or a class, so the type of implementation (class or function), is the factor deciding which naming convention to use.
a common mistake is to prefix the name of the function with the keyword decorator.
for more information about decorators see [link](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0318/)