# Using the name "function" for a variable in Python code

Tags: coding-style, python

Is using the word `function` for the name of an argument considered bad style in Python code?

```py
def conjunction_junction(function):
    pass # do something and call function in here
```

This pattern occurs all the time, especially [in decorators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10957409/python-naming-conventions-in-decorators). You see `func`, `fn` and `f` used all of the time but I prefer to avoid abbreviations when possible. Is the fact that it's the name of a type enough to warrant abbreviating it?

```
>> type(conjunction_junction).__name__
'function'
```

Comment: As long as it doesn't override anything and it doesn't cause syntax color issues (it doesn't) - I personally don't mind.

Comment: `function` does highlight in blue here on stack overflow :)

Comment: @Mike: That's because SO uses a generic highlighter. Let me add the language tag so it highlights properly.

Comment: @NiklasB. Thanks! I'll do that in the future.

Comment: > I prefer to avoid abbreviations when possible < A great philosophy (mine as well)!  There's no problem with using `function`, but given how common `func` is, I wouldn't be against abbreviating this specific name.

Comment: I tend to use `callback` in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not a reserved keyword, so I don't see why not.

From the [Style Guide](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#function-and-method-arguments)

> If a function argument's name clashes with a reserved keyword, it is
>   generally better to append a single trailing underscore rather than
>   use an abbreviation or spelling corruption. Thus class_ is better than
>   clss. (Perhaps better is to avoid such clashes by using a synonym.)

Comment: `str` and `list` are also no reserved keywords. You still want to avoid using them as identifiers. Of course in this case, `function` is also not a builtin class, module or function name, so it's okay to use it (though I've seen `func` being used more commonly, maybe for the exact same reason that OP started the question: they weren't sure whether it's okay to use `function`)

Answer (score 3):

Using `function` is perfectly fine.

There is nothing in the [style guide](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#function-and-method-arguments) about it specifically. The reason that the use of type names such as `str` and `list` is highly discouraged is because they have functionality within the language. Overwriting them would obscure the functionality of the code. `function` on the other hand, does nothing.

I suspect `func`, `fn`, and `f` are used because they are all shorter than typing `function` ;)